# Parallel sum of elements in a large Array

Tags: java, c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I have program that sums the elements in a very large array. I want to parallelize this sum.

```
#define N = some_very_large_no; // say 1e12
float x[N]; // read from a file
float sum=0.0;
main()
{

for (i=0, i<N, i++)

sum=sum+x[i];

}
```

How can I parallelize this sum using threads (c/c++/Java any code example is fine)? How many threads should I use if there is 8 cores in the machine for optimal performance?

EDIT: N may be really large ( larger than 1e6 actually) and varies based on the file size I read the data from. The file is in the order of GBs.

Edit: N is changed to a large value (1e12 to 1e16)

Comment: You can use c++11 threads  for this purpose. You may need to experiment optimal thread number but  I think that less than 8 threads will give the best results (like 5-6) due to caching constraint etc...

Comment: Is this a Java, C, or C++ question?

Comment: I assume its `Multilingual` :D

Comment: Is there a *reason* for this to get so many downvotes? This is a very valid question to me. Simply showing that *you can split* then add the results is no good at all.

Comment: @Eugene Hover over the downvote button.

Comment: @AndrewThompson did not get your down vote for this. Are you suggesting I use any hypothetical no of threads in my 8 core system ?

Comment: Dare I ask, how many floats we're talking about here? Because, 1. Benchmark a single-scan solution since you have them all in memory anyway. 2. Unless you have enough floats (dependent on your working system) I'll be amazed the number required to beat that time with a multi-threaded solution is not substantial. Your example of 1-million floats will more-than-likely NOT do it. Crunch them in sets for a series of generated FFTs and you might have good reason for this. A simple summation? Not likely.

Comment: optimal no of threads is an experiment. too much is even worse than serial code. two threads per core is some staring point.

Comment: *"did not get your down vote for this."*  Congrats!  You did now earn it by implying I had.  -1

Comment: Reading the data in from a file will be many thousands of times slower than the summing computation. How often do you need to sum it? Thousands of times? If not - parallelisation won't help. Measure before trying to optimise.

Answer (score 3):

In Java you can write

```
int cpus = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
// would keep this of other tasks as well.
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cpus);

float[] floats = new float[N];

List<Future<Double>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
int blockSize = (floats.length + cpus - 1) / cpus;
for (int i=0, i < floats.length, i++) {
    final start = blockSize * i;
    final end = Math.min(blockSize * (i+1), floats.length);
    tasks.add(service.submit(new Callable<Double>() {
        public Double call() {
            double d= 0;
            for(int j=start;j<end;j++)
                d += floats[j];
            return d;
        }
     });
}
double sum = 0;
for(Future<Double> task: tasks)
    sum += task.get();
```

As WhozCraig mentions, it is likely that one million floats isn't enough to need multiple threads, or you could find that your bottle neck is how fast you can load the array from main memory (a single threaded resource)  In any case, you can't assume it will be faster by the time you include the cost getting the data.

Comment: taking into consideration that an array of primitives is most likely (in Java) a contiguous block of memory and a simple for looping will easily get "predicted" by the CPU, I think (and I am not even close to be sure), more cpus will do less. Can we expect such a thing?

Comment: We can expect that more cpus might be better, but not worse.  How much better depends on what you are doing.  For such a simple operation, I would suspect not much.

Answer (score 3):

You say that the array comes from a file. If you time the different parts of the program, you'll find that summing up the elements takes a negligible amount of time compared to how long it takes to read the data from disk. From [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) it follows that there is nothing to be gained by parallelising the summing up.

If you need to improve performance, you should focus on improving the I/O throughput.

Comment: you are right. As I can parallelize the computation, I am considering this first. I am not sure if the io's can be parallelized, I mean reading from the disk.

Comment: @StackUnderflow Save for data stored a a multi-volume mirror, not likely. I can't see single-spindle read-op getting any benefit at all from parallelization. but then there are those lovely SSD's, aren't there =P

Answer (score 2):

you can use many threads(more than cores). But no of threads & its performance depends on ur algorithm as how they are working.
 As array length is 100000 then create x thread & each will calculate arr[x] to arr[x+limit]. where u have to set limit so that no overlapping with other thread & no element should remain un-used.
thread creation:

```
   pthread_t tid[COUNT];
    int i = 0;
        int err;
        while (i < COUNT) 
        {
            void *arg;
            arg = x; //pass here a no which will tell from where this thread will use arr[x]
            err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, arg);
            if (err != 0)
                printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
            else
            {
                //printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");
            }

            i++;
        }
       // NOW CALCULATE....
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) 
        {
            pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
        }
}
```

---

```
void* doSomeThing(void *arg) 
{
    int *x;
    x = (int *) (arg);
   // now use this x to start the array sum from arr[x] to ur limit which should not overlap to other thread
}
```

Comment: it might be the case that this *optimization* will only do harm, at least in Java. You might break branch prediction, and the Threads might even take longer to "schedule" each other, the doing actual work.

Comment: @Eugene yes but its totally depends on the use of the threads if they are struggling for any shared resources then we have to use some locking but this will cause problems...! so threads are useful only if algorithms is parallel.

Comment: @Eugene I'm not sure about that. If the object is not volatile, then Java's not going to wait to synchronize thread access.

Comment: @Eugene i haven't used java threads so can't say anything...but basics can't be wrong...so threading may increase performance or decrease its depends on applications algorithm...not on c/c++ or java threads.!!

Answer (score 0):

Use **divide and conquer** algorithm

- Divide the array into 2 or more (keep dividing recursively until you get an array with manageable size)
- Start computing the sum for the sub arrays (divided arrays) (using separate **threads**)
- Finally add the sum generated (from all the threads) for all sub arrays together to produce **final result**

Comment: Your first step is unnecessary. Also, this doesn't really answer the question

Comment: as it is an array, you can just fix the optimal length for sum, and then proceed further by index. thread 0: 0 to oLength-1, thread 1: oLength to 2*oLength - 1..... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the time-cost of reading the file is almost certainly going to be much larger than that of calculating the sum. Is it a text file or binary? If the numbers are stored as text, then the cost of reading them can be very high depending on your implementation.

You should also be careful adding a large number of floats. Because of their limited precision, small values late in the array may not contribute to the sum. Think about at least using a double to accumulate the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pthreads in c to solve your problem
Here is my code for N=4 ( you can change it to suit your needs )
To run this code, apply the following command :
gcc -pthread test.c -o test
./test

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 5
pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
pthread_mutex_t mutexsum;
int  a[2500];
int sum = 0;
void *do_work(void* parms) {

    long tid = (long)parms;
printf("I am thread # %ld\n ", tid);

    int start, end, mysum;

    start = (int)tid * 500;
    end = start + 500;
    int i = 0;
printf("Thread # %ld with start = %d and end = %d \n",tid,start,end);
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        mysum += a[i];
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexsum);
printf("Thread # %ld lock and sum = %d\n",tid,sum);
    sum += mysum;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexsum);

pthread_exit(NULL);


}
void main(int argv, char* argc) {
    int i = 0; int rc;
pthread_attr_t attr;
         pthread_mutex_init(&mutexsum, NULL);
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexsum, NULL);
printf("Initializing array : \n");
for(i=0;i<2500;i++){
a[i]=1;
}
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        printf("Creating thread # %d.\n", i);

        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, &do_work, (void *)i);
        if (rc) {
            printf("Error in thread %d with rc  = %d. \n", i, rc);
            exit(-1);
        }

    }
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
printf("Creating threads complete. start ruun " );
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    }
    printf("\n\tSum : %d", sum);
pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexsum);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP supports built-in reduction. Add flag -fopenmp while compiling.

```
#include <omp.h>
#define N = some_very_large_no; // say 1e12
float x[N]; // read from a file
int main()
{

float sum = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
for (i=0, i<N, i++)
  sum=sum+x[i];

return 0;
}
```